# To have two Pg queries in one Python method

Tags: python, postgresql

Thank you for Denis who solves the first bug!

**How can you have two Postgres queries in one Python method?**

**Example where the 2nd query is not run**

```
def comp_func(pgmasi):
        pgmasi.query("""CREATE TABLE courses (
        course_id       SERIAL PRIMARY KEY)""")
        pgmasi.query("""CREATE TABLE files (    # not executed for some unknown reason
        file_id         SERIAL PRIMARY KEY""")
```

Comment: What is setBinaryStream? It doesn't seem to be part of the Python standard library.

Comment: If you're not sure what the "command" is in Python, what is it doing in your code?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some comments to your code indicating what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you missed closing parentheses in the line as error message says:

```
pgmasi.query("INSERT INTO files('binf','file_name') VALUES(file,file_name)"
```